# Rails paperclip upload to S3 returns bucket URL but folder doesn't exist on bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

For some reason my upload on using Paperclip isn't actually created on my S3 bucket.

```
@user.update(params.require(:user).permit(:photo))
render json: { photo_url: @user.photo.url(:thumb) } }
```

> s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/example123/users/photos/000/000/417/thumb/blob?1496258964

---

I switched to a new bucket and it works normally. But in my original bucket it doesn't seem to create the user 417 folder or the file.

What should I be looking in relation to bucket permissions to allow Paperclip to create the folder and file for my image upload?

Answer (score 0):

S3 doesn't have directories. It just stores string keys.  Your file just has name `example123/users/photos/000/000/417/thumb/blob?1496258964`. There are some tools that will show you it as directories tree, but these are just names.

I think you should check permissions for that bucket that doesn't work